# UITableViews as pick lists

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a view controller with 2 labels - each to be populated from lists in 2 separate table controllers. In my view controller I have 2 variables (*temp* and *temp_1*) to receive the data from the table controllers and populate the labels. 
When I call the first table view and select an item that works fine and my first label is populated, when I then call the second table view that works too and my second label is populated - except that the first label is now blank - because temp is now blank.
I have attached my prepareForSegue from my first table view showing me passing my variable *temp* back to my view controller. (My second is similar and passes back *temp_1*)
Thanks for any help.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "return_1" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? main_ViewController {
            if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
                destination.temp = array1[row] as! String

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that what you are saying in words is not what in fact you are actually doing. You say "back to my view controller", as if you were *returning* from the table view to the main view controller. That is what you *want* to do and what you *should* do, but it isn't what you're doing (I'm guessing). I think you've set up your storyboard with a normal *segue* from the table view to the main view controller. That doesn't go *back*; it makes a *whole new main view controller*. So of course the old label value is missing, because this is a *different* view controller from the one with the old label value (which effectively is still there, two layers down, covered up by this new instance).

What you want is an *unwind segue*. That is how you say "go back" in a storyboard.

Comment: Your guess is correct and thanks to you I have solved a problem I have had for  days.